# laravel: Call to a member function delete() on null

Tags: laravel

I got this error when I tried to add a feature of delete, to the posts just by clicking on the delete button.
Where am I doing wrong?

Delete post function in PostController:

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id)
{
    $post =Post::where('id',$post_id)->first();
    $post->delete();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
}
```

Comment: I'm in a mobile right now I was suggesting to do directly delete instead of first because as far as I now first returns an array ...

Comment: Method `first()` return `Model|Builder|null` (https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_first)

Comment: Okay, Thank you... @Joanquin Javi. I'll check it out.

Comment: Okay... I'll check it... @Marek Skiba. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$post`object is null. Maybe you are sending a wrong $post_id. If you check that the post exists before delete you avoid that error.

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id)
{
    $post =Post::where('id',$post_id)->first();

    if ($post != null) {
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
    }

    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Wrong ID!!']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone. But still, there is a trouble. It is showing the message that the post has been deleted, but it does not. It is still on my dashboard and database.

Comment: Edited to show a different message if post_id it's wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Victor 
Ya, I did that. And it worked too, But, I don't understand what is the problem. The 'users' table contain the column 'id', which links the 'posts' table with the column 'user_id' of 'posts' table. I tried the above code, It showed 'Wrong Id', Then I edited 'id', with 'user_id', Again same message. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have `Post` where `id = $post_id`, you can try with `firstOrFail` method:

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id)
{
    $post =Post::where('id',$post_id)->firstOrFail();
    $post->delete();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
}
```

or start using [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-model-binding) and then you don't need care about that `Post` with `id = $post_id` exist or not:

So first you need add binding in the `RouteServiceProvider::boot`:

```
$router->model('post', 'App\Post');
```

then in route you need change to this:

```
Route::post('post/{post}/delete', [
    'as' => 'post.delete', 'uses' => 'PostController@getDeletePost'
]);
```

and then your controller looks like this:

```
public function getDeletePost(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
}
```

If you have still problem, you should show us how you build POST form that send request to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that your $post variable is null/undefined.

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id) {
  try {
    $post = Post::where('id',$post_id)->first();
  } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Failed']);
  }

  $post->delete();

  return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but ... No, it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Actually,I tried @victor 's method. It did work. It is showing successfully deleted message now, but is not deleting the posts from my dashboard and database.

Answer (score 0):

You eloquent query is not returning a result so the $post variable is empty which is causing the error.

Instead use findOrFail which will throw exception if no record is found with provided id.

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$post->delete();
return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
```

If ModelNotFound exception is thrown then that means Post record does not exist in database with the provided Id.