# Laravel5.6 "Call to a member function delete() on null " , delete a row in table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-controller

I want to delete a row from table. The function I used in controller is:

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $category->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

However it throws me an error:

> Call to a member function delete() on null

When I use this code:

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $category = Category::find($id);
    dd($id);
 }
```

It is showing the correct id i.e.

> "1"

And when I use

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $category = Category::find($id);
    dd($category); // or
    dd(Category::find($id);
 }
```

I get the output

> null

on the screen.

Comment: the category might not be existing

Comment: i have Category model and also included use App\Category ;

Comment: [i think that is the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421415/laravel-call-to-a-member-function-delete-on-null)

Comment: Check database does id 1 exist in db ?

Comment: Just because you created and imported the model class doesn't mean the model you are requested (id of 1) exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel: Call to a member function delete() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421415/laravel-call-to-a-member-function-delete-on-null)

Comment: i have two model post and category both have id attribute and yes id 1 exist in db .

Comment: show the view from where you are passing these values

Comment: <td>
                            <a href="{{route('category.delete',['id' => $category->id])}}" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                        </td>

Comment: Check if `Category` points to the proper class. Do `composer dump` to be sure your autoloaders are in the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the error you're getting is probably due to no category exists in the database for the given ID.

Then, when you try to find the category for that ID:

```
$category = Category::find($id);
```

The value of `$category` variable is `null`. Therefore, you get an error for trying to call `delete()` method on `null`. Under the hood, it would be the same as doing the following:

```
null->delete();
```

Which, doesn't work.

You could check the value of `$category` before trying to delete it. Or you may use a query to delete all records matching a given condition, in your case `id = $id`. This way:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Category::where('id', $id)->delete();
    return redirect('/')->back();
}
```

Refer to **Deleting Models By Query** in the [Eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#deleting-models) for details on how that works.

Comment: thaks it works when i used this Category::where('id', $id)->delete(); instead of $category = Category::find($id) ;
   $category->delete() ;

Comment: can you pls explain me what problem i was getting

Comment: @AsharKhan I've just updated Sebastian's answer to include details on what's happening and why you were getting that error.

Comment: I would argue this only hides the problem, it doesn't solve it.  The real question is why Category::find($id) isn't finding your model.  Either the $id is wrong, the model doesn't exist, or your model class is set up to use the wrong primary key.  In either case, your code should not continue.

Comment: @Devon It depends on how the OP wants to handle the issue. I've seen apps that simply ignore the non-existent entity and continue the flow. But, yes, I personally would use a `findOrFail()` call or another kind of handling that informs the app's user the record they're trying to delete does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the following *(I ensured that the $id was passing from the view)*:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $vendor = Vendor::findorFail($id);
    $vendor->delete():
}
```

for some reason when I did the following it showed *null*

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $vendor = Vendor::find($id);
    $vendor->delete():
}
```

This is the view part:

```
     {!! Form::open(array(
         'style' => 'display: inline-block;',
         'method' => 'DELETE',
         'onsubmit' => "return confirm('".trans("global.app_are_you_sure")."');",
         'route' => ['vendor.destroy', $vendor->vendor_id])) !!}
     {!! Form::submit(trans('global.app_delete'), array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger')) !!}
     {!! Form::close() !!}
```